# Is there a way to tell if a program is still running a method?

Tags: java

I'm running a method from my main that generates data and I also fork a thread that monitors a queue that the method is writing to and if there's data it saves it to a disk.

My problem is in the past I would multi-thread it and was able to monitor the life of other threads but I'm not sure how to do that if its just the main method? The issue the method is generating data slowly and using sleep or !queue.empty() doesn't work as as soon as it empties the queue the forked file writer process stops.

I know worst case I can write to the file in the method generating the data, but other than that is there anything I can do to monitor if another method is still being executed?

Comment: Are you using a `LinkedBlockingQueue`?  That will block the caller until something has been added to the queue so your file writer won't stop when the queue is empty.  You could use the `LinkedBockingQueue` and enqueue some special object to indicate that your process is done adding data to the queue.

Comment: You say `fork` a thread, which makes no sense, really: are you `fork`ing a new _process_ or `Thread.start()` ing a new thread? That makes a huge difference in the relevant answer...

Comment: @MattCrinklaw-Vogt intresting, didn't know that. I was using ArrayBlockingQueue but I can give LinkedBlockingQueue a shot.

Comment: @Matt I'm doing `thread.start();`

Comment: Well both ArrayBlockingQueue and LinkedBlockingQueue should have the same interface.  The "ArrayBlockingQueue.take" method is the method that will suspend the calling thread until something is added to the queue.

Comment: @MattCrinklaw-Vogt I tried LinkedBlockingQueue and got the same effect..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a good job for an [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). Create it in your main method:

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

`ExecutorService` is basically a wrapper around a queue and a set of threads that are waiting on that queue (10 in example above). The moment something appears in the queue (is submitted), exactly one thread picks it up:

```
pool.submit(someWork);
```

Where `someWork` is a Runnable, that e.g. wraps data to be written to disk and writing procedure. When you are done in the main thread, you simply ask the `pool` to terminate gracefully:

```
pool.shutdown();
pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This code will wait 60 seconds for other threads to finish and process all items in the queue.

Show us more code, I can assist you in refactoring it. If you don't want to go that far, there are methods in some Java collections that block when the queue is empty and wake the thread when something appears.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz. I know how to do this, I think its a great idea..because I was only running one thread I didn't think of this..Thanks I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [jstack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html) command to print a stack trace of JVM threads.